# How to print front pages before verse pages

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

I need to do a report on *JasperReports* (*iReport 3.7.2*) where the front pages appear before the page of the verse. (It is for a certificate).

I tried to do two subreports, each in a detail band, where the first has the sql to get the information from the front pages and the second subreport to the back pages.

However, I am only able to make them appear interspersed.

Example:

> Page 1-Front of the certificate 1
>
> Page 2-Back of the certificate 1
>
> Page 3-Front of the certificate 2
>
> Page 4-Back of the certificate 2

When in fact I wanted to

> Page 1-Front of the certificate 1
>
> Page 2-Front of the certificate 2
>
> Page 3-Back of the certificate 1
>
> Page 4-Back of the certificate 2

You know how should I solve this?

Comment: What is the data source you are using for the main report?  When you say you have "two subreports, each in a detail band", you mean you have two separate detail bands, with one subreport in one and one subreport in the other?

Comment: Also are you linking any fields from the main report to the subreport?

Comment: The data source is the database. Yes, I mean two separated detail bands with one subreport in one and one subreport in the other. I am linking some fields from the main report to both subreports.

Comment: @FelipeQueiroz Did you try to use group? One group - one certificate. It will be better if you post you `jrxml` file or at least the details about your datasource and the screenshot of 'TOBE' design.

Comment: @AlexK At the moment I am without the code. But in the job I will test your sugestion and post the jrxml here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem by concatenating the front pages with pages of verse as seen in the following link: [How to merge two pdf documents into a single report in JasperReports?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2666001/how-to-merge-two-pdf-documents-into-a-single-report-in-jasperreports)