# How to concatenate n reports programmatically (portrait+ landscape Orientation)

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I've a report (orientation: portrait) that contain a subreport`, the subreport contain diagram and tables,so I need to change its orientation to Landscape, and when jasper do not allow that, (hope it's wrong), I should generate multiple reports which will be concatenated,
the problem is: I don't know the number of reports that will be generated and how to order them programmatically.

```
Title 1 (portrait)
     tile 1.1 (landscape)

Title 2
     title2.1

.
.
 Title n
     title nn
```

Is it realizable, or should I look o other tool that may realize support both portrait and landscape orientation in the same report

Comment: You could always generate them individually, and then concatenate them together. Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/8278526/3340

Comment: thanks for reply @jschoen, this what i'v done,i've created the reports dynamicaly (for loop) "report"+i+".jasper" (i++ in each title) , my question 's how to concatenate the n reports in the right order. thanks

Comment: thanks @Alex K, may be yes,using JRPrintPage,can I keep the difference of the orientation (portrait / landscape ),

Comment: @RaisMEd yeah, the orientation can be different for each JRPrint object.

Comment: thanks for reply friends , I'm working on it, I'll notify you when I finish. thanks sooo much

Comment: Hello, I couldn't realize this task using JRPrintPage (JasperPrint.addPage), the orientation of the 2nd report follow automatically the first one.

Comment: i've concatenated  reports with differents orientations successfully usng JRPdfExporter and (JRExporterParameter.JASPER_PRINT_LIST).but the new report kept the old pages numbers (starting bu 1 for each report), how can I fix? thanks :)

Comment: I am not sure there is away to fix that, but feel free to ask a new Question on SO. Maybe somebody can help out