# How can I have multiple JRBeanCollectionDataSource in JasperFillManager.fillReport?

Tags: java, jsp, jasper-reports

I'm using Jasper Report generation in my application (Java application with JSP).
I have a JSP page with a table and I was able to successfully generate a .xslx file with that data through jasper reports.

I used below lines in the code,

`dataList` is a `ArrayList` of `Beans` one row in the table is one persons information. So we can create a Bean for that and all row's data will be an `ArrayList of Person Beans` i.e. `ArrayList<Person> personalData =  new ArrayList<Person>();`

```
JRBeanCollectionDataSource beanColDataSource = new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(this.dataList);

JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, parameters, beanColDataSource);
```

So when it is one table It's straight forward in that way. How about I have multiple tables and I want to create a Report to print those ?

As in the image those tables are completely independent from each other.

so now I have multiple ArrayLists (data sources)

```
ArrayList<Person> personalData =  new ArrayList<Person>();
ArrayList<Vehicle> vehicleData =  new ArrayList<Vehicle>();
ArrayList<Problem> problemData =  new ArrayList<Problem>();
```

But I can only use one `JRBeanCollectionDataSource` as in the below code

```
JRBeanCollectionDataSource beanColDataSource = new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(this.dataList);

JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, parameters, beanColDataSource);
```

So how can I successfully make the report with all the data tables I have ?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can construct a number of subreports, where you populate each subreport using `JasperReportDataSource`. So you might use `$F{data.personal}`, `$F{data.vehicle}` and `$F{data.problem}` as references for each subreport.

Each will return a new data source for use within the subreport.